# Keras predict not working for multiple GPU's

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, keras

I recently implemented this make_parallel code (https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/blob/master/utils/multi_gpu.py) for testing on multiple GPUs. After implementing the predict_classes() function did not work with the new model structure, after some reading I switched to using the predict function instead. This function only works using certain batch sizes, for example a batch size of 750 works, while 500, 100 and 350 fails with the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (348,15) into shape 
(350,15)
```

The training was completed with a batch_size of 75. Any idea why this is happening or how I can fix?

```
pointFeatures = np.zeros((batchSize,featureSize))
libfeatures.getBatchOfFeatures(i,batchSize,pointFeatures)

pointFeatures = pointFeatures.reshape(batchSize, FeatureShape.img_rows, 
                FeatureShape.img_cols, FeatureShape.img_width, 
                FeatureShape.img_channels)

pointFeatures = pointFeatures.astype('float32')

results = model.predict(pointFeatures, verbose=True, 
          batch_size=FeatureShape.mini_batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using make_parallel function, you need to make sure number of samples is divisible by batch_size*N, where N is the number of GPUs you are using. For example:

```
nb_samples = X.shape[0] - X.shape[0]%(batch_size*N)
X = X[:nb_samples]
```

You can use different batch_size for training and testing as long as the number of samples is divisible by batch_size*N.